# contentEditable ExecCommand "bold" fails to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

I'm having a lot of trouble getting an execcommand "bold" to fire on my `contentEditable` div. I've tried a lot of solutions on similar questions here to no avail. I understand there are some bugs with execCommand; any help would be very much appreciated!

This is my code:

```js
$("#bolder").on('click', function() {
    document.execCommand("bold", false, null);
});
```

```css
.text {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 90%;
     left: 0%;
     border: solid;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
    <button id="bolder" type="button">Bold</button>
 <div class="text"  contenteditable="true">
   This won't work 
 </div>
 <img class="loader" id="loader" src="Social_Icons/loader.svg">
</div>
```

I'm using the latest Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. But:

- If you just want to make *some text* inside the editor becomes **strong**, you have to select the text first.
- If you want to make all of the text becomes **strong**, you can focus the editor and use `document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)` to select all of the text before applying `bold`.

This example to make all of the text to **bold** after clicking `Bold` button:

```js
$("#bolder").on('click', function() {
    $('[contenteditable]').focus();
    
    document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)
    document.execCommand("bold", false, null);
});
```

```css
.text {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 90%;
     left: 0%;
     border: solid;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
    <button id="bolder" type="button">Bold</button>
 <div class="text"  contenteditable="true">
   This won't work 
 </div>
 <img class="loader" id="loader" src="Social_Icons/loader.svg">
</div>
```